# How to group certain fields in a json under new key?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, group-by, nested

I have a JSON and I want to group some fields under a new key. How can I do that in python?
Here is the initial data and desired output - I want to add new key "percents", so that it groups years:

```
{"data": [{
        "id": 1,
        "search_key": "London",
        "2021": 0.018,
        "2022": 0.019,
        "2023": 0.02,
        "2024": 0.02,
        "2025": 0.02,
        "2026": 0.02,
        "2027 and next": 0.02
    }, {
       ...
       }]}
**desired:**  
 {"data": [{
        "id": 1,
        "search_key": "London",
        "percents":{
                       "2021": 0.018,
                       "2022": 0.019,
                       "2023": 0.02,
                       "2024": 0.02,
                       "2025": 0.02,
                       "2026": 0.02,
                       "2027 and next": 0.02
                       }    
     }, {
         ...
         }]}
```

Comment: You parantheses `[{` do not match. Please fix your code.

Comment: Also, please be more specific. What does "group some fields under a new key" mean?

Comment: What have you tried till now?

Comment: I was thinking about group by but it works with agg func only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And though it might not be pretty, the code below should be able accomplish this task.

First, we iterate through the dictionary and using regex to look for keys that are in a format of a *year*. Once we find these keys, we add the key-value pair to a new dictionary called `dates`. We also need to remove these dates from the dictionary. Now we have two dictionaries, `dates` and `newData` - `{'data': [{'id': 1, 'search_key': 'London'}]}`.

Now we add `dates` to `newData` with the extra key `percents`.

```
import re
data = {"data": [{
        "id": 1,
        "search_key": "London",
        "2021": 0.018,
        "2022": 0.019,
        "2023": 0.02,
        "2024": 0.02,
        "2025": 0.02,
        "2026": 0.02
        }]
}
dates = {k:v for k,v in data['data'][0].items() if re.match(r'.*([1-3][0-9]{3})', k) is not None}
newData = {"data":[{k:v for k,v in data['data'][0].items() if k not in dates}]}
newData['data'][0]['percents'] = dates
```

output

```
{'data': [{'id': 1, 'search_key': 'London', 'percents': {'2021': 0.018, '2022': 0.019, '2023': 0.02, '2024': 0.02, '2025': 0.02, '2026': 0.02}}]}
```

Comment: thank you! but I think regex is a bit excessive since I don't have any more years beside
"2021", "2022", "2023", "2024", "2025","2026", "2027 and next", so these keys are the same for the rest of the json.

Comment: I know, but this answer should help future users if they ever want to group certain keys. Those keys need to be unique in some way. But sure.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I actually did not provide the code. Will do now!

Answer (score -1):

this is ugly but it worked.

```
for i in c["data"]:
    i['percent'] = {}
    if i["2021"]:
        i['percent'].update({"2021":i['2021']})
        del i["2021"]
    if i["2022"]:
        i['percent'].update({"2022":i['2022']})
        del i["2022"]
    if i["2023"]:
        i['percent'].update({"2023":i['2023']})
        del i["2023"]
    if i["2024"]:
        i['percent'].update({"2024":i['2024']})
        del i["2024"]
    if i["2025"]:
        i['percent'].update({"2025":i['2025']})
        del i["2025"]
    if i["2026"]:
        i['percent'].update({"2026":i['2026']})
        del i["2026"]
    if i["2027 and next"]:
        i['percent'].update({"2027 and next":i["2027 and next"]})
        del i["2027 and next"]
```